# How to select maximum date within all rows in SQL Server statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

- `Charges` (IdCharges IDENTITY(1,1), PRN Varchar(10), Created (DateTime), SeasonCode Varchar(10));
- `Sales` (IdSales IDENTITY(1,1), PRN Varchar(10));
- `Bounty` (IdBounty IDENTITY(1,1), BountyTran varchar(10));

And this SQL code to insert sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Charges VALUES ('111','2023-06-01','10.1'); 
INSERT INTO Charges VALUES ('222','2023-06-02','10.2'); 
INSERT INTO Charges VALUES ('333','2023-06-03','10.3');

INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ('111');  
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ('222');
INSERT INTO SALES VALUES ('333');

INSERT INTO Bounty VALUES ('WWW');
INSERT INTO Bounty VALUES ('DDD');
INSERT INTO Bounty VALUES ('FFF');
```

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCharges]
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        K.Bounty AS BountyTran
        'C' AS CODE, 
        LEFT(C.SeasonCode, CHARINDEX('.', C.SeasonCode + '.') - 1) AS SCODE
    FROM 
        dbo.Sales S
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Charges C ON S.PRN = C.PRN
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Bounty B ON S.IdBounty = B.IdBounty
                     AND C.Created >= @StartDate
END
```

I want to select maximum `C.Created` - for example:

- If stored procedure is executed with `'2023-06-02'`, then the output should be `('DDD', '10', '2023-06-03'), ('FFF', '10', '2023-06-03')`

Comment: Try the window function `MAX(C.Created) OVER() AS LatestCreated`. That will return the max Created date over the entire result set. The `OVER()` defines the scope over which `MAX()` is applied. An empty scope means the entire result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Window function

You forgot that I put the IdBounty  in the SALES  table because the join is done based on it

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCharges]
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        B.BountyTran AS BountyTran,
        --'C' AS CODE, 
        LEFT(C.SeasonCode, CHARINDEX('.', C.SeasonCode + '.') - 1) AS SCODE
        ,max(Created) OVER() AS LatestCreated
    FROM 
        dbo.Sales S
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Charges C ON S.PRN = C.PRN
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Bounty B ON S.IdBounty = B.IdBounty
                     AND C.Created >= @StartDate
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/aT18T44D)

Comment: You can drop the `order by (select 0)` content of the `OVER()` clause, since order is not needed for the `MAX()` function.

Comment: @TN, Thank you For your point,I am used to to use order by